# Mysql query from two tables as parent and child objects

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am creating an Angularjs app with two tables "Contact Group" and "Contact List". The contact list table items have corespondent id to items in the contact group.
What I want to achieve is a MySQL/Sqlite select query that will have each contact list items as a child object of its parent.

```
contact_group
  id | title 
 ------------
  1  | friends
  2  | mates
  3  | family

contact_list
 id  | gID | name | number
--------------------------
  1  |  1  | dave |0208500
  2  |  1  | dan  |4213839
  3  |  1  | sans |5656434
  4  |  2  | fola |1918982
  5  |  3  | brian|2398343
  6  |  5  | grace|0934232
```

Select query results examples (this is what i want to get)

```
id: 1
title: friends
child: {id:1, name:dave, number:0208500}, {id:2, name:dan, number:4213839},{id:3, name:sans, number:5656434}
```

I case there is another way of doing it, this what i want to achieve. I have created an accordion with title from the contact_group title. Under each accordion are the correspondent contacts from the contact_list.

I will be glad if anyone can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve this you will have to use MySql `GROUP_CONCAT` (documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Using `GROUP_CONCAT` we will be able to join all matching rows from the contacts TB into a string in one column. With some more formatting of the text we glue together from the contacts TB and additional usage of `CONCAT` we will build the string in this column as a JSON string that you will then be able to work with on your application.

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.title,
    CONCAT(
      '[',
      GROUP_CONCAT(
          CONCAT(
              '{"id":',
              b.id,
              ', "name":"',
              b. `name`,
              '", "number":"',
              b.number,
              '"}'
          ) 
          ORDER BY
              b.`name`
      ), ']')
      AS people
FROM
    contact_group AS a
LEFT JOIN contact_list AS b ON a.id = b.gID
GROUP BY
    a.id,
    a.title
```

And this is the result we will get:
[image]

*Don't forget to add Indexes and Foreign keys to your tables so query processing would be better.*

**SQLLITE Version:**
in order to adjust the query to sqllite, there are 2 features that need to be changed.
SqlLite uses `||` operator instead of `CONCAT` and it does not support `ORDER BY` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT`. so for the SQLLITE DB the query will look like this:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.title,
    '[' ||
      GROUP_CONCAT(
            '{"id":' ||
              b.id ||
              ', "name":"' ||
              b. `name` ||
              '", "number":"' ||
              b.number ||
              '"}'


      ) || ']'
      AS people
FROM
    contact_group AS a
LEFT JOIN contact_list AS b ON a.id = b.gID
GROUP BY
    a.id,
    a.title
```

---

[MySQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6749/1)

[SqlLite Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/063cf/13)

Comment: Thanks @Lupin Please can you write this query as sqlite (websql). I am having problem with the double and single quotes and it is generating error.

Comment: Create a fiddle of this in SQLITE and try to play with it, share the fiddle and i will have a look

Comment: It works in MySql but i have been trying to make it work websql but is not working

Comment: Updated with SqlLite Fiddle and query

Answer (score -1):

Try the below query,

```
select * from contact_group join contact_list on contact_group.id= contact_list.gid
```

Comment: Thanks, i have already tried this. it does not group the contact_list as object under contact_group